# SOLVED Trigger to check the availabilty of a reservation mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am working on a school project and I can't figure out how to properly set this kind of trigger in my database.

I need to manage a **reservation** table.

One can make a reservation for a certain day (Date) at a specific start time.

Based on the services requested from the user, the reservation will have also an end time which is calculated as the sum of each requested service.

What I would like to do is create a trigger (or something else) which won't allow a user to insert a reservation if there is no availabilty for that specific day at that specific hour.

For example, reffering to the table below, I don't want to allow the insert of a reservation between 10:30 and 11:00 on 08/22/19.

This is an example of the table:

```
| id |Customer|    Date    | startTime     | endTime  |
|----|--------|------------|---------------|----------|
| 1  |    1   | 08/22/19   |  10:30:00     | 11:00:00 |
| 2  |    2   | 08/22/19   |  12:30:00     | 13:30:00 |
| 3  |    3   | 09/22/19   |  10:30:00     | 10:45:00 |
```

This is the query I wrote in order to insert into the table:

```
INSERT INTO reservation(Customer, Date, startTime, endTime) VALUES 
((SELECT id from customer WHERE id='1' ), '08/22/19', '103000', '103000'); #endTime is initialized as startTime
```

This is the trigger I've tried to run:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS CheckHour;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  TRIGGER CheckHour AFTER INSERT ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF 
        EXISTS(  SELECT *
                 FROM reservation
                 GROUP BY new.Date, new.startTime
                 HAVING COUNT(new.Date) > 1 AND COUNT(new.startTime) > 1)
    THEN
        DELETE FROM reservation WHERE id = new.id;
        SIGNAL sqlstate '20000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DUPLICATED RESERVATION';
    END IF; 
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

What happens is that as soon as I insert on reservation I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'reservation' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.   0.000 sec
```

I'd really appreciate if you can help me, even with a different approach. Thank you very much!

Comment: A trigger does not seem appropriate at all. Run a select query first to check availability, then do the insert or show an error message if the reservation cannot be made. What you are doing here is, deleting a record that should not even have been saved in the first place. Besides, handling exceptions is more expensive than anticipating them.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I should run a select query everytime before an insert on that table, right?

Comment: @Anonymous what I can't understand is how to link the select and the insert? I mean, after i've written the select that checks the availability for that time, what should I do? 
Sorry, but I am at the beginning. Thank you again.

Comment: Not looking on your EXISTS expression - simply remove DELETE statement. SIGNAL is enough (but change SQLSTATE to any of CLASS '40').

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this problem with this trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS CheckHour;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  TRIGGER CheckHour BEFORE INSERT ON prenotazione
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF 
        EXISTS(  SELECT *
                 FROM prenotazione
                 WHERE new.Data = prenotazione.Data AND
                       new.OraInizio > prenotazione.OraInizio AND
                       new.OraInizio < prenotazione.OraFine)
    THEN
        SIGNAL sqlstate '20000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DUPLICATED RESERVATION';
    END IF; 
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```